# Can internet sharing (Ethernet->WiFi, 10.6.8, iMac) extend an existing WiFi network from an AirPort?

Tags: wifi, airport, internet-sharing

I want to leave my AirPort Extreme (version 76400.10) at one end of my house, and use my iMac with Internet Sharing activated at the other end of the house. Ideally, I would be able to walk around the house with my phone and seamlessly connect to whichever access point has the better signal. I was told this could be done if both networks have the same network name and password, but I'm having trouble setting it up. I have both Airport and iMac set up with the same WEP password (WPA not available on iMac internet sharing).

Still my phone insists that there are two separate networks and doesn't magically stay connected to the internet as I walk around without manually switching.

Comment: as long the input is Ethernet (cable) you can, you can not extend Input WiFi output WiFi since you WiFi car can not do that.

Comment: But my iPhone does not seem to connect to the nearest access point as I walk to the other end of the house. It eventually gives up, switches to CELLULAR, than I manually connect to wifi again, this time to the closer device. I want smooth, total coverage throughout the house

Comment: lets clarify, Your main source of internet is the AirPort or the Mac? in order to set up seamless network throughout the home, one has to be set in the "repeater" mode, what that does is just repeats the same WiFi.

Comment: Internet comes from modem to AirPort. Ethernet cable from AirPort to iMac. AirPort generates Wifi network, iMac generates wifi network with same name and password. I'll look up repeater mode, but the problem in the first place is WiFi from the AirPort is pretty weak over where the iMac is